# Do - Try/Catch - While block with 2 functions inside

Tags: c++, while-loop, try-catch

I've got issue with do try catch while block - I have put there 2 functions which can throw an exception. There are 3 parameters user should type (each has it's own requirements). When I type wrong first param - loop is doing well - user has to type again. Problem is when I type good first param, but wrong second - I'm getting an infinite loop.

Here's the code:

```
**main**:
int main()
{
    int DL;
    pair <bool,bool> DS;
    bool dobrze = true;

    do
    {
        try
        {
            DL = getDl(&dobrze);
            DS = getDS(&dobrze);
        }
        catch(int err_no)
        {
            cout << "Wrong parameter:";
            switch (err_no)
            {
                case 0: cout << " length.";
                    break;
                case 1: cout << " big letters.";
                    break;
                case 2: cout << " other characters.";
                    break;
            }
            cout << endl;
         }
     }while (dobrze == true);
}
**functions**
int getDl (bool dobrze)
{
    int dl;
    cout << "Length [1 - 64]: ";
    cin >> dl;

    if ( dl <= 0 || dl > 64 )
    {
        dobrze = false;
        throw 0;
    }

    dobrze = true;
    return dl;
}
//------------------------------
pair<bool,bool> getDS(bool dobrze)
{
    pair<bool,bool> ds;

    cout << "Big letters [0/1]: ";
    cin >> ds.first;

    if ( ds.first != 0 && ds.first != 1) 
    {
        dobrze = false;
        throw 1;
    }
    dobrze = true;
//-----------
    cout << "Other characters [0/1]: ";
    cin >> ds.second;

    if ( ds.second != 0 && ds.second != 1) 
        throw 2;

    dobrze = true;
    return ds;
}
```

What's the reason of this?

Comment: `DL = getDl(&dobrze);`
`DS = getDS(&dobrze);`
Why you pass address of `dobrze` instead of `dobrze` itself?

Comment: Avoid exceptions during stream IO, use some proper error handling, instead. Also, throw some std::exception or something derived.

Comment: Throwing exception because someone has fat fingers and types in something incorrect is *not* an exceptional occurance.  Therefore you shouldn't throw exceptions in this instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't entirely believe your characterization of the program's behavior.  Your loop terminates only when `dobrze` is `false` when execution reaches the bottom, but you (attempt to) set that variable `true` on successful input.  You only set it `false` on input error, just before throwing.

Even so, your behavioural discrepancy may arise from the fact that you do not set dobrze before the second `throw` in `getDS()`.

Also, as @justanothercoder pointed out, you are passing a `bool *` to your functions, but they are expecting a `bool` argument.  This is flat wrong.  You can either declare the functions to accept a `bool *`:

```
// Pass a pointer
DL = getDl(&dobrze);

// ...

int getDl (bool *dobrze) {
    // ...
    *dobrze = true;
    // ...
}
```

or you can use pass by reference

```
// just pass the variable ...
DL = getDl(dobrze);

// ...

int getDl (bool &dobrze) {
    // otherwise unchanged ...
}
```

I think, though, that the whole dobrze business is messy nonsense if, at it appears, the point is just to determine whether to cycle the loop.  You already know that by whether you catch an exception inside, so why do you need the variable?  Consider building around this sort of skeleton instead:

```
while (true) {
    try {
        DL = getDl();
        DS = getDS();
    } catch (int err_no) {
        // cycle the loop:
        continue;
    }
    // exit the loop:
    break;
}
```

Comment: Just put the `break;` inside the `try{}` block.

Answer (score 1):

Here the argument is a pointer.

```
DL = getDl(&dobrze);
```

Here it is not:

```
pair<bool,bool> getDS(bool dobrze)
```

Unfortunately for your debugging attempts, `bool` is one of very few data types that implicitly initializes from a pointer to itself.  In effect your call is

```
DL = getDl((bool)(&dobrze));
```

which is the same as

```
DL = getDl(nullptr != &dobrze);
```

which is just

```
DL = getDl(true);
```

There's nothing in your program that can change the `dobrze` variable in main and end the loop.

You could have caught this by turning on warnings... your compiler should have informed you that the lines `dobrze = true;` and `dobrze = false;` write to a variable (the local copy) that is never read.